# How to center a View in a Component using React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing an issue when trying to center a View in a component using React Native. I've tried a few approaches using justifyContent and alignItems, but haven't achieved the desired result.

Here's my current code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>My Component</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   justifyContent:"center",
   alignItems:"center"
  },
});

export default App;
```

Can someone help me understand how to properly center a view in a component using React Native?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you want to center it horizontally and vertically? (middle of the screen?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I center a component on the screen in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77757713/how-can-i-center-a-component-on-the-screen-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

This style will center your component.

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
```